# New Model within ViewModel error on ID of 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a viewmodel.

```
    public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public RegisterModel Register { get; set; }
    public Producer Producer { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Producer> Producers { get; set; }

}
```

In the view, the user puts in their registration credentials and then selects a producer that they are a part of.  They can also create a new producer on the page as well.  However, when they do this my ModelState is invalid because the Producer doesn't have an ID field.  This is a new Producer record and I shouldn't need to assign an ID before it is created in my database, right?  ID is my identity field in SQL.  I noticed that my scaffolded code for other domain models passes back an ID of 0 without any issues.  Am I doing this correctly at all?  Is this related to the viewmodel?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Producer class:

```
    public class Producer
{
    public int ProducerID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Postal { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Website { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Wine> Wines { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to post an ID from the page.  What does your view code look like and your controller action that's handling this?  If it's to do with the database, what does your database handling code look like.  If your producer table has an ID field then your producer class will need one as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to have a view model that is specific to the create action that doesn't have this key, although for reuse some do.

In that case, as you mentioned zero should be just fine. Ensure the key is written to the page though, check for a hidden field that has zero in it.

Comment: I did what you said.  I have a bit of JS that changes the value in teh dropdown to 0 when they select a new producer.  THen I handle a producer id of 0 in my controller and the model is valid, eventhough 0 will never be an actual producer.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you do not assign an ID before inserting into the database. But the viewmodel is going to be invalid because it expects ProducerID to be filled. Try annotating the producerID field with

```
[Key]
public int ProducerID { get; set; }
```

If, however, the user selects an already existing Producer, and then that ProducerId is not associated with the registration, then you will obviously have an issue where the user is not associated with a Producer.

Comment: I tried this and the Key attribute didn't work.  None of the annotations on the producer model flow through to the viewmodel either.  I think I may populate it with 0, then handle that within the code.